# Compare/Use data of a different website programmatically

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I want to use data of a website of a friend of mine (which means, he allows me to do so) programmatically. He updates the availability of a certain walking route (due to weather and on) regularly by changing an image. So he has 3 possible images (red, orange and green) for that route that are displayed like this (and he will always only have 1 of these "active"):

```
<img src="closed.png" id="route_icon"/>
<img src="possible.png" id="route_icon"/>
<img src="open.png" id="route_icon"/>
```

and I want to use that information on a website of mine to display the current status of that track also, but in a slightly different way.

I'd do roughly something like

```
var route_status = gettheinformation('page.com'); // This is the block I am interested in
if(route_status == closed){
var displayed_status="The track is closed";
} else....
```

I literally have no clue on how to do that first part. How would I get that information?

Comment: You are looking for `XMLHttpRequest` or use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Answer (score 0):

Fetch page html and parse:

```
fetch('pageUrl')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(html => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

    const image = doc.querySelector('#route_icon');
    const [status] = image.src.split('.');
  });
```